# Flutter. Row with MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween overflowed

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-widget, flutter-row

I am new in flutter and I'm trying to implement screen like this:

[image]

As you can see I need to make something like a table. I ran into a problem while implementing table rows. Here is my code:

```
 Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Flexible(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text("2.", ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Text(text: "This is second with very long text"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 8),
              Text("500"),
            ],
          ),
```

But I'm getting the error:

> A RenderFlex overflowed by 42 pixels on the right.

For some reason my text ("This is second with very long text") doesn't move to a new line, but goes off screen.

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

You have to wrap your `Text("This is second with very long text")` widget inside `Flexible` widget like this:

```
Row(
   mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
   children: [
       Flexible(
           child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text("2."),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Flexible(
                      child: Text("This is second with very long text"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 8),
            Text("500"),
     ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a ListTile for that.

```
ListTile(
  leading: Text("2. "),
  title: Text("This is second with very long text"),
  trailing: Text("500"),
)
```

This is much simpler to implement and handles long text automatically.
You can set padding etc as you wish. You can find more information about list tiles in the [official documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

you need a Column, to wrap the widgets inside, inside the column you need a first Row that will hold the first and second,
then a HorizontalLine, and then the rest of the rows:

Please, see the example below

```
Container(
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
  child: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
    children: [
      //first row:
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('First', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          Text('Second', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ]
      ),
      //This SizedBox gives space between widgets
      SizedBox(height:5),
      Container(color: Colors.black, height: 2, width: double.infinity),
      //This SizedBox gives space between widgets
      SizedBox(height:5),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          //In order to make the Text multi-lined you need to wrap-it into a SizedBox widget
          SizeddBox(
            //as I can see, the middle text widget is almost the 70% of the total width
            //You can get the total width from MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
            child: Text('This is first', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),         
          ),
          Text('500', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ]
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Text('2', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          //In order to make the Text multi-lined you need to wrap-it into a SizedBox widget
          SizeddBox(
            //as I can see, the middle text widget is almost the 70% of the total width
            //You can get the total width from MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
            child: Text('This is second with a very long text', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),         
          ),
          Text('12', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ]
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          Text('3', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
          //In order to make the Text multi-lined you need to wrap-it into a SizedBox widget
          SizeddBox(
            //as I can see, the middle text widget is almost the 70% of the total width
            //You can get the total width from MediaQuery.of(context).size.width
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.7,
            child: Text('This is third with a long text too', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),         
          ),
          Text('150', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ]
      ),
      
    ]
  )
```

In this code, you can change the styling and etc as you wish.

I would suggest you to extract the the Row widget that holds the number, the text and the score in a Stateless widget, or in a method that returns Widget object, but it's very soon for this.

I hope I helped you.

Enjoy Flutter!